# How to highlight all specific characters given, with regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Let's consider a constant **main** which is defined something as :

```
const main = "Work on $ @ & but not 1 2 3";
```

Now, a function named as **parse()** which is used as :

```
const final = parse(main);
alert(final); // Work on <b>$</b> <b>@</b> <b>&</b> but not 1 2 3
```

So, we find that the special characters i.e **$**, **@** and **&**, have been updated with some html. So, firstly I tried to make the parse function, which seemed like this :

```
const parse = (val) => {
  val = val.replace(/\$/gim, "<b>$</b>").replace(/@/gim, "<b>@</b>").replace(/\&/gim, "<b>&</b>");
  return val;
}:
```

My code works but lastly I realised that I have to write a lot of code if I have to give support for all characters ! So, is there any shorcut ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `|` which means "or" and use `$&` which means the matched string.

```js
const main = "Work on $ @ & but not 1 2 3";

const parse = (val) => {
    val = val.replace(/\$|@|&/gim, "<b>"+"$&"+"</b>");
      return val;
    };

    const final = parse(main);
    alert(final); // Work on <b>$</b> <b>@</b> <b>&</b> but not 1 2 3
```

Comment: This is an **often** asked duplicate. It doesn't need an answer, just a close vote (when you can) and if necessary a comment.